# SwiftUI can not return View on function

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying return `View` based selected menu item on function. But it throws error:

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

There my code:

```swift
enum MenuItem {
  case Main
  case Report
}
struct Menu: View {
  @State var activeItem: MenuItem = .Main

  private func getActiveView() -> View {
    switch activeItem {
      case .Main:
        return DashboardView()
      case .Report:
        return ReportView()
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
    ...
    getActiveView()
    ...
  }
}

struct DashboardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Contact")
    }
}
struct ReportView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Contact")
    }
}
```

Im new on `SwiftUI`. Any ideas how to return `View`?

Comment: You are not sufficiently explaining your situation.  What is activeItem?  Where is the `body`?  What do you mean by returning DashboardView or ReportView?

Comment: @ElTomato I don't think those are relevant to the question. Why do you think they are relevant? OP just wants to return two different views.

Comment: @ElTomato Updated code. Based on menu I should show View

Comment: @Sweeper he didn't have enum, initially.  Also, are you suggesting that you don't need the body clause in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2**

Here is a solution tested with Xcode 12b / iOS 14

```
struct Menu: View {
    @State var activeItem: MenuItem = .Main

    // make function ViewBuilder
    @ViewBuilder
    private func getActiveView() -> some View {
        switch activeItem {
        case .Main:
            DashboardView()     // don't use 'return' as it disables ViewBuilder
        case .Report:
            ReportView()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        getActiveView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

SwiftUI gives us a `type-erased wrapper` called `AnyView` that we can return.

**Tested Solution:**

```
struct Menu: View {
    @State var activeItem: MenuItem = .Main
    
    func getActiveView() ->  some View {
        switch activeItem {
        case .Main:
            return AnyView(DashboardView())
        case .Report:
            return AnyView(ReportView())
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        getActiveView()
    }
}
```

> **Note:** `type-erased wrapper` effectively forces Swift to forget about what specific
> type is inside the `AnyView`, allowing them to look like they are the
> same thing. This has a performance cost, though, so don’t use it
> often.

For more information you can refer to the this cool article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-return-different-view-types

Comment: I would try not to use AnyView. AnyView takes away essential static type information about the view tree that otherwise helps SwiftUI perform efficient updates. This means that SwiftUI now has more work to do to compare the differences between what has changed and what hasn't. The article that you like to even suggests that you should use Group over using AnyView, as Group is a ViewBuilder.

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you there is performance cost involved but it solve the issue without extra efforts.

Comment: But you can use a the ViewBuilder syntax which results in more readable code without the performance cost.